# What national agency in Russia codifies research ethics?

Tags: ethics, russia

I am coordinating the funding proposal for a joint Austrian–Russian research project.  The proposal needs to briefly discuss compliance with relevant ethics regulations and guidelines, preferably not just at the institutional level but also the national or international level.  For the Austrian side this is easy, as I already know that the relevant guidelines are the [Austrian Agency for Research Integrity](https://oeawi.at/)'s [Guidelines for Good Scientific Practice](https://oeawi.at/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/OeAWI_Brosch%C3%BCre_Web_2019.pdf) and the [European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/info/research-and-innovation_en)'s [Ethics for Researchers](http://dx.doi.org/10.2777/7491).  But what are the corresponding guidelines in Russia?

That is, are there any national agencies in Russia that issue ethics regulations and/or guidelines for scientific research in general?  If so, what specific publication of theirs should we be reading, accounting for, and mentioning in the proposal?

So far the only somewhat relevant agency I've found is the [Independent Interdisciplinary Ethics Committee on Ethical Review for Clinical Studies](http://ethicuni.ru/).  However, this body seems to be concerned only with clinical research, and the project we're proposing doesn't involve clinical research.

Comment: Surely your Russian collaborators should know this?

Comment: Probably, but they're currently busy writing other parts of the proposal and I want to get this section out of the way now. In any event, having the answer posted publically here will no doubt help others who are in a similar situation (particularly in a pre-proposal phase).

Comment: Presumably the Austrian equivalent agency operates within the administration of some government department, e.g. Department of Education & Science or whatever. So logically you might, with the assistance of some Russian speaker, enquire via phone/email with the counterpart government department in Russia.